# Using mod_rewrite for GET variables in a Wordpress blog page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a wordpress blog, with the default .htaccess settings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my wordpress blog, I have created a page called "mypage". Using my rewrite settings, it is shown in the address bar as `http://www.mysite.com/mypage`.

I am using a custom page template and am processing some things, which include the use of GET variables. For instance:

```
if (isset($_GET='word')) { echo $_GET['word]; }
```

So, `http://www.mysite.com/mypage?word=dog` will display "dog".

The problem I am having is rewriting the URL so that it can look like: `http://www.mysite.com/mypage/dog`, still being able to access "dog" as the GET variable.

I am not too good with mod_rewrite rules to begin with, but working from within a wordpress installation is throwing me an extra curveball.

Does anyone know what I need to add to my .htaccess to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/([^/])/?$ mypage?word=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The L flag instructs .htaccess to stop processing rules, and QSA appends the query string since you might have other GET parameters on the end of the URL.

[Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: This may work if the page was actually named mypage.php, but within a wordpress installation, the page "names" are generated by the above posted htaccess rewrite rules which must remain in place.

Comment: Well try removing the .php since Apache doesn't really care what you're redirecting to, just where it is.

Comment: I've tried to apply this to something I'm trying to do, however I don't believe $_GET['Pin'] (in my case) is being seen anymore by the page. Is it the QSA that is meant to leave the query string viewable by the PHP page?

Comment: Actually, it seems like it's not working at all. I'm getting Page Not Found whenever I try to view the new page. I'm using `RewriteRule ^readers/([^/])/?$ details?Pin=$1 [QSA]` within the BEGIN Wordpress block in htaccess